# refactoring xsd elements with same elements?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, xsd

I have below xsd elements.

```
 <xsd:element name="requestOne" type="tns:RequestOne"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="RequestOne">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>some comment</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:element name="requestTwo" type="tns:RequestTwo"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="RequestTwo">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>other comment</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

It has two complex elements but inside them there is duplicated code. How can i refactor above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new element you can use `ref` to refer to an existing one, `tns` in the sample below refers to the name space defined by the schema

```
<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string"/>

...

<xsd:complexType name=RequestOne">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="tns:id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

...
```

Though, this does not really reduces the number of characters to write, in that simple case. You might even have a look at how to define abstract types which, similar to object orientated languages, get inherited by children:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AbstractType" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name"BaseType">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

the children now need to inherit from the abstract type in the following manner:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ChildOne">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="tns:AbstractType">
            <xsd:element name="newElement" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Where `newElement` is just a new element defined by the child.

---

Edit: to be more precise, the `id` element is not really inherited like in an object oriented language but you achieve the same effect. The difference is, that you have to add the base-type within the XML of the concrete realization.

```
<ChildOne>
    <BaseType>
        <id>someId</id>
    </BaseType>

    <!-- elements defined by child one goes here -->
    <newElement>new Element</newElement>
</ChildOne>
```

Comment: Roman, thanx for ur answer. do i need to create RequestTwo similar to RequestOne? thanx

Comment: yes, that's why I edited my comment. For this simple case you don't really spare characters, if the element you are referring to is a bit more complex then it makes more sense. Though, referring to is in my opinion always better in case of typos or maybe wrongly assigned types for some non-intuitive elements.

Comment: @user755806 I've updated the example as abstraction definition was not 100% correct and I've further included an example of how the XML according to the schema will look like when dealing with XSD abstraction